# probable scope issue(maybe)?

Tags: java, while-loop, scope

So I am making a little command line lottery game (comments in code explain everything ) however when I generate the random number my code does not shorten it to three digits like I hoped, other than that the game works and is playable except every once and a while one of the randomly generated numbers is over a thousand and is not shortened. any ideas (sorry if its hard to read I don't know a lot of java concepts yet so I'm stuck with basic logic operators)

```
/* Dustin Shropshire 5.14.2016 

test program : LotteryGame ,
generate a random number and then separate them into their place values
and store them in variables allows user to take a guess at the value
allows user to take a guess at the value and then take their input
and determine if all the numbers match in the exact order, or if they
match in any order, or if at least one of the numbers match */




import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryGame {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int  lotteryDigitNumber1 = 0, lotteryDigitNumber2 = 0, lotteryDigitNumber3 = 0; // the lottery numbers  place to hold its three digits 
        int userGuessInput = 0, userGuessDigit1 = 0, userGuessDigit2 = 0, userGuessDigit3 = 0;  // users guess and a place to hold its three digits
        int seperateLotteryNumber = 0, seperateUserNumber = 0; // used to seperate the number 
        int shortenVariable = 0; //used to shorten a randomaly generated variable if its over 1000;
        int moneyCounter = 10000; //starting amount of money
        int randomLotteryNumber = 0; //initialzing this out of the loop in the hopes that it puts everythin in scope


    while(moneyCounter > 0){

         randomLotteryNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 100 );  // generates a random number between 0 and 1100 exlusing 1100

        System.out.println("please enter a three digit number as your guess:");

        userGuessInput = input.nextInt();

     //this while loop is used to prevent someone from entering a number less than 100 and greater than 999
    while((userGuessInput >= 1000) || (userGuessInput <= 99)){ 

        System.out.println("sorry that is not three digit number please enter a three digit number:");

        userGuessInput = input.nextInt(); } 

        System.out.println("the random lotttery number was " + " " + randomLotteryNumber);

    // this if statment is used if a randomly generated number is over 1000 to truncate to a 3 digit number
    if(randomLotteryNumber >= 1000){  

            shortenVariable = randomLotteryNumber / 10; 

        lotteryDigitNumber1 = shortenVariable / 100; 
        seperateLotteryNumber = shortenVariable % 100; 
        lotteryDigitNumber2 = seperateLotteryNumber / 10; 
        lotteryDigitNumber3 = seperateLotteryNumber % 10; 
    }

    else if( randomLotteryNumber <= 999){  

        lotteryDigitNumber1 = randomLotteryNumber / 100;
        seperateLotteryNumber = randomLotteryNumber % 100;
        lotteryDigitNumber2 = seperateLotteryNumber / 10;
        lotteryDigitNumber3 = seperateLotteryNumber % 10;}
        //used to seperate lottery numbers digits into individual variables


        userGuessDigit1 = userGuessInput / 100;
        seperateUserNumber = userGuessInput % 100;
        userGuessDigit2 = seperateUserNumber /10;
        userGuessDigit3 = seperateUserNumber % 10;
        //used to seperate lottery number digits into individual variables 


    if(userGuessInput == randomLotteryNumber ) { 

            moneyCounter = moneyCounter + 10000;

            System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + randomLotteryNumber + " "  + "you guessed right you earn $10,000" 
            + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);

        //this if statment is only true when both the lottery number and the user guess is exactly matched
        } 
    else if ((userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber2
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber3
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber1
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber1 
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber2)){
                //this logic block is true when the lottery number and user guess have all the same numbers but in a different order 

                moneyCounter = moneyCounter + 3000;

                System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + randomLotteryNumber + " "  + "you guessed all the numbers right just in the wrong order you earn $3,000" 
                                    + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);



            }
    else if ( (userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber1) || (userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber2) || (userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber3)
                || (userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber1) || (userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber2) || (userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber3)
                || (userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber1) || (userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber2) || (userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber3)){
                                //this logic block is only true when the user guesses one of the same numbers as the lottery number 

                                moneyCounter = moneyCounter + 1000;

                                System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + randomLotteryNumber + " "  + "you guessed one number right you earn $1,000" 
                                    + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);

                            }
    else if( (userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber2
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber3
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber1
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber1 
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber2)){
                             //this logic block is used if none of the numbers in any order is matched 

                            moneyCounter = moneyCounter - 1000; 

            System.out.println("oh sadly none of the numbers match you lose  $1000"  +  " "  + "current money:"  +  " " +  moneyCounter);
            }




}


    System.out.println("your out of money thanks for playing");
        }

    }
```

Comment: any scope issue will be prone to `compile-time` Error . its never will raise any `exception` or prone to `infinite-loop` @pawsome

Comment: How do you know the number is not shortened? If it's based on printout, then are you supposed to print out `randomLotteryNumber`? I mean, you select only 3 digits if number is over 1000, but I don't see you modify the `randomLotteryNumber `, which means you are printing out the same number you generated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a scoping issue, it's an issue of using `Math.random()` incorrectly. Math random returns a value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), and it seems you're implicitly assuming it will have no more than one digit of precision. `Math.random()` may very well return a number like `0.913`, which multiplied by `1000` would be `913`, and then when you add `100` will become `1013`, giving you a four digit number. The proper way to generate a three digit integer would be to do something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random(); // should be done only once when the program starts
int randomLotteryNumber = 100 + rand.nextInt(900);
```

Comment: even if its a 4 digit number I have part of the code that truncates it to 3 digits that's what I'm curious isn't working

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Random()` will return a number from `0.0` to `0.99...`

Multiplying it with 1000 may give you a number like 999, +100 gives a four digit number.

Here is a little complicated solution

```
randomLotteryNumber = (randomLotteryNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 1000)) > 99 ? 
                                              randomLotteryNumber : 
                                              randomLotteryNumber + 100;
```

---

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

Another easy way would be to use Java Streams

```
Random r = new Random();
randomLotteryNumber = r.ints(100, 1000).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

This will return a random integer from 100 (inclusive) to 1000 (exclusive).

Comment: thank you for the help I'm specifically curious as to why even if its a 4 digit number my code that should shorten it to three digits isn't working .

Comment: @pawsome You're using `%100`, for example if we take `1001` : `1001 % 100 = 1` So it gives unwanted results with some numbers. The best way is to generate it immediately like given above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies within your printouts. You are printing out `randomLotteryNumber` and not the 3 digits you selected from the generated number. Seeing as you never modify that number you always print out the number you generate.

One of examples from your code:

```
System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + randomLotteryNumber + " "  + "you guessed one number right you earn $1,000" 
                                    + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);
```

You should probably print (the `toString()` part is only there to make sure no arithmetic operations are done and might be replaced with someting else):

```
System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + lotteryDigitNumber1.toString()+lotteryDigitNumber2.toString()+lotteryDigitNumber3.toString()+ " "  + "you guessed one number right you earn $1,000" 
                                    + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);
```

Answer (score 0):

got an answer I was printing the wrong value as well as had a logic issue if a number larger than a thousand had 0's in it,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryGame {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int  lotteryDigitNumber1 = 0, lotteryDigitNumber2 = 0, lotteryDigitNumber3 = 0; // the lottery numbers  place to hold its three digits 
        int userGuessInput = 0, userGuessDigit1 = 0, userGuessDigit2 = 0, userGuessDigit3 = 0;  // users guess and a place to hold its three digits
        int seperateLotteryNumber = 0, seperateUserNumber = 0; // used to seperate the number 
        int shortenVariable = 0; //used to shorten a randomaly generated variable if its over 1000;
        int moneyCounter = 10000; //starting amount of money
        int randomLotteryNumber = 0; //initialzing this out of the loop in the hopes that it puts everythin in scope


    while(moneyCounter > 0){

         randomLotteryNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 100 );  // generates a random number between 0 and 1100 exlusing 1100

        System.out.println("please enter a three digit number as your guess:");

        userGuessInput = input.nextInt();

     //this while loop is used to prevent someone from entering a number less than 100 and greater than 999
    while((userGuessInput >= 1000) || (userGuessInput <= 99)){ 

        System.out.println("sorry that is not three digit number please enter a three digit number:");

        userGuessInput = input.nextInt(); } 



    // this if statment is used if a randomly generated number is over 1000 to truncate to a 3 digit number
    if(randomLotteryNumber >= 1000){  

            shortenVariable = randomLotteryNumber / 10; 

        lotteryDigitNumber1 = shortenVariable / 100; 
        seperateLotteryNumber = shortenVariable % 100; 
        lotteryDigitNumber2 = seperateLotteryNumber / 10; 
        lotteryDigitNumber3 = seperateLotteryNumber % 10; 

    //may delete this logic later
    if(lotteryDigitNumber2 == 0){
        lotteryDigitNumber3 = seperateLotteryNumber;
    }


    }

    else if( randomLotteryNumber <= 999){  

        lotteryDigitNumber1 = randomLotteryNumber / 100;
        seperateLotteryNumber = randomLotteryNumber % 100;
        lotteryDigitNumber2 = seperateLotteryNumber / 10;
        lotteryDigitNumber3 = seperateLotteryNumber % 10;
        shortenVariable = randomLotteryNumber;
        }
        //used to seperate lottery numbers digits into individual variables

        System.out.println("the random number is" + " " + shortenVariable);

        userGuessDigit1 = userGuessInput / 100;
        seperateUserNumber = userGuessInput % 100;
        userGuessDigit2 = seperateUserNumber /10;
        userGuessDigit3 = seperateUserNumber % 10;
        //used to seperate lottery number digits into individual variables 


    if(userGuessInput == shortenVariable ) { 

            moneyCounter = moneyCounter + 10000;

            System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + shortenVariable + " "  + "you guessed right you earn $10,000" 
            + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);

        //this if statment is only true when both the lottery number and the user guess is exactly matched
        } 
    else if ((userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber2
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber3
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber1
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber1 
            || userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber2)){
                //this logic block is true when the lottery number and user guess have all the same numbers but in a different order 

                moneyCounter = moneyCounter + 3000;

                System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + shortenVariable + " "  + "you guessed all the numbers right just in the wrong order you earn $3,000" 
                                    + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);



            }
    else if ( (userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber1) || (userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber2) || (userGuessDigit1 == lotteryDigitNumber3)
                || (userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber1) || (userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber2) || (userGuessDigit2 == lotteryDigitNumber3)
                || (userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber1) || (userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber2) || (userGuessDigit3 == lotteryDigitNumber3)){
                                //this logic block is only true when the user guesses one of the same numbers as the lottery number 

                                moneyCounter = moneyCounter + 1000;

                                System.out.println("the lottery number was:" + " " + shortenVariable + " "  + "you dident guess all the numbers but got some right you earn $1,000" 
                                    + " " + "currentmoney:" + " " + moneyCounter);

                            }
    else if( (userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber2
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber3
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber1
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber2 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber1 
            || userGuessDigit1 != lotteryDigitNumber3 && userGuessDigit2 != lotteryDigitNumber1 && userGuessDigit3 != lotteryDigitNumber2)){
                             //this logic block is used if none of the numbers in any order is matched 

                            moneyCounter = moneyCounter - 1000; 

            System.out.println("oh sadly none of the numbers match you lose  $1000"  +  " "  + "current money:"  +  " " +  moneyCounter);
            }




}


    System.out.println("your out of money thanks for playing");
        }

    }
```